# Getting error on rhive.env(): cant't connect to a Rserver at x.x.x.x

Tags: r, hadoop, tcp, hive, rserve

I run Hadoop cluster (master + 3 slaves)+Hive server and I want to use RHive over it.
I installed R environment on every computer.
Rserve was installed on every node and RHive was installed on the master.
I get error trying to run RHive on master:

```
> rhive.env()
Hive Home Directory : {Hive home directory}
Hadoop Home Directory : {Hadoop home directory}
Hadoop Conf Directory : {HAdoop configuration directory}
Default RServe List
x.x.x.8     hadoop-slave1 x.x.x.9     hadoop-slave2 x.x.x.10    hadoop-slave3
warning: cant't connect to a Rserver at x.x.x.8     hadoop-slave1:6311
warning: cant't connect to a Rserver at x.x.x.9     hadoop-slave2:6311
warning: cant't connect to a Rserver at x.x.x.10    hadoop-slave3:6311
Disconnected HiveServer and HDFS
Warning messages:
1: In socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE) :
  x.x.x.8     hadoop-slave1:6311 cannot be opened
2: In socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE) :
  x.x.x.9     hadoop-slave2:6311 cannot be opened
3: In socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE) :
  x.x.x.10    hadoop-slave3:6311 cannot be opened
```

Rserve listens on TCP port 6311 on slave1, slave2 and slave3.
I tested it with:

```
nc -z hadoop-slave1 6311
Connection to hadoop-slave1  6311 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

What could be connection problem?

Answer (score 0):

RHive calls for Rserve url 'hadoop-slave1:6311' as listed in {hadoop home}/conf/slaves

I opened R and testd connction to this url:

```
% R 

> library("Rserve") 

> c <- RSconnect(host = " hadoop-slave1", port = 6311)
```

then connection failed.

I tried to connect by IP and it succeed!

The problem was DNS configurations!!!

There are 2 possible solutions:
1. fix DNS server, then connecting by name will work
2. open {hadoop home}/conf/slaves and fix slave names to IP's